# how to get net_device and net_device_operation in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

I wanted to know tcp/ip sequence on linux kernel.
So, I have checked network code on kernel.

First, I checked kernel code when user calls sock function(for tcp/ip).

when user calls sock function for tcp/ip protocol, system call happen and
System call function calls sock_create function.
And then Sock_create function calls inet_create function using parameter of user sock function.

After that, I checked kernel code when user calls write function for socket(tcp/ip).

most of function operation and object for socket what kerenel needs for transmit is bound in inet_create.
but, I don't know where object of net_device and dev->netdev_ops function is bound.
when is net_device object and ops of netdevice bound and where is they bound ???

follwing sequence is my thinking about socket transmit sequence(for tcp/ip).(linux kernel ver is 3.18.)

```
write -----user space
----------------------------- System call

= >vfs_write   ------------------VFS layer
~~~~>
=> file->f_op->aio_write ( sock_aio_write - bound by system call of user sock function )
=> sock->ops->sendmsg ( inet_sendmsg - bound by inet_create function)

-----------------------------
inet_sendmsg
=>sk->sk_prot->sendmsg ( tcp_sendmsg  - bound by inet_create function )
=============================
tcp_sendmsg
~~~~~>
=> icsk->icsk_af_ops->queue_xmit ( ip_queue_xmit : bound by inet_create function )
=============
=> ip_queue_xmit
~~~~~>
=> netdev_start_xmit
=> __netdev_start_xmit
=> ops->ndo_start_xmit ( when is net_device object and ops of netdevice bound and where is they bound ???)
=================
(For example )
=>el3_start_xmit//(device driver)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

net_device and dev->netdev_ops are bound in the network interface controller(NIC) driver code, this binding occures when the NIC driver is loaded and it recognizes the hardware. For example here is where it is bound in intel's driver [e1000](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/netdev.c#L7029).

Then when you attempt to send a packet from user mode the routing tables determine which NIC to use, and the appropriate driver code is called.

Comment: I have one more question. which function determine NIC(net_dev) using routing table?? I want to check the code.

Comment: The usual way to do it is call ip_route_connect. For TCP, the function that finds the netdev using the routing table is __ip_route_output_key which is called by ip_route_connect, which is called by tcp_v4_connect.